# Is it possible to include online image in video?

Tags: video, analytics

This would be for analytics (views) purpose rather than rendering in my case. A GET request with parameters would also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean include something in the frames of the video itself that would dynamically download all or part of that frames image?

The most common container formats at the moment, e.g. mp4, Ogg, or codec formats (h.264 etc) do not support this as far as I am aware.

You can add timed tracks to an MP4 container that allow you add formatted 'subtitles' - these subtitles can include HTML markup that will be interpreted locally and displayed, and it is also possible to have the player trigger certain functions based on this markup, or simply based on the video timestamp, but that requires you to add functionality to the player, and restricts any solution to one using your own player.

Comment: Utilizing closed caption could be handy. Thanks for the pointer.